# cannot get the <span></span> texts

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

cannot get the span text within the "table", thanks !

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url1 = "url"

content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1,"lxml")
table = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "iw_component","id":"c1417094965154"})
rows = table.find_all('span',recursive=False)
for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "iw_component","id":"c1417094965154"})`

In the above line, `findAll()` returns a list. 
So, in the next line you are getting the error because its expecting an HTML string.

If you expect only one table, try using the following code. Just replace

`rows = table.find_all('span',recursive=False)`

with

`rows = table[0].find_all('span')`

If you expect multiple tables in the page, run a for loop on the table and then run the rest of the statements inside the for loop.

Also, for pretty output, you can replace the `tabs` with spaces as in the following code:

```
row = row.get_text()
row = row.replace('\t', '')
print(row)
```

The final working code for you is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url1 = "url"

content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1,"lxml")
table = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "iw_component","id":"c1417094965154"})
rows = table[0].find_all('span')
for row in rows:
    row_str = row.get_text()
    row_str = row_str.replace('\t', '')
    print(row_str)
```

Regarding `recursive=False` parameter, if it's set to false, it will only find in direct children which, in your case will give no result.

[Recursive Argument in find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument)

> If you only want Beautiful Soup to consider direct children, you can pass in `recursive=False`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use python 2.x, here is a python 3.x solution, since I do not have a python 2.x environment at the moment :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib


url1 = "<URL>"

# Read the HTML page
content1 = urllib.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1, "lxml")

# Find the div (there is only one, so you do not need findAll) -> this is your problem
div = soup.find("div", class_="iw_component", id="c1417094965154")
# Now you retrieve all the span within this div
rows = div.find_all("span")

# You can do what you want with it !
line = ""
for row in rows:
    row_str = row.get_text()
    row_str = row_str.replace('\t', '')
    line += row_str + ", "
print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using lxml instead of beautifulsoup:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

req = requests.get("<URL>")
raw_html = html.fromstring(req.text)
spans = raw_html.xpath('//div[@id="c1417094965154"]//span/text()')
print("".join([x.replace("\t", "").replace("\r\n","").strip() for x in spans]))
```

Output: Kranji Mile Day simulcast races,   Kranji Racecourse, SINClass 3 Handicap   -    1200M TURFSaturday, 26 May 2018Race 1, 5:15 PM

As you see, the output need a little formatting, spans is a list of all spans text, so you can do any processing you need.